# How to handle json format error shows if the table is empty

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, zend-framework

Am fetching values from a table, its working perfectly. When the table is empty am getting aler box json formating error. How can i handle that error?

my sql query is given below, am using php zend framework

```
public function getProductsAction(){

     $oProductModel = new Application_Model_Db_Table_Products();
     $oSelect = $oProductModel->fetchAllProductItems();

     echo Zend_Json::encode($this->_helper->DataTables($oSelect, array('product_id','e.ename as employee_name','name','brand','conditions','about','image_path','reserved_price','Max(b.bid_amount) as amount')));

}
```

and view page is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#product-table').dataTable({
        <?php if(Qsm_User::isAdmin()){ ?>
            "sDom": 'Tlfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/js/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [{
                        "sExtends":    "collection",
                        "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                        "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                    }]
            },
       <?php } ?>
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sAjaxSource": '/buyproduct/api/get-products',

        "aoColumns": [  
            {"sTitle":"ID", "bVisible":false}, 
            {"sTitle":"Emp Name", "bVisible":true},
            {"sTitle":"Product", "sWidth": '10%'},
            {"sTitle":"Brand", "sWidth": '10%'},
            {"sTitle":"Condition", "sWidth": '10%'},
            {"sTitle":"Description", "sWidth": '20%'},
            {"sTitle":"Image","sWidth": '18%',
             "mData": null,
             "bSearchable": false, 
             "bSortable": false,
             "fnRender": function (oObj){
            var actions = "";
            actions += "<span class=''>\n\
             <img src='/uploads/gallery/" + oObj.aData[6] + "' alt='Image' title='Image' class='style_prevu_kit' width='0px' height='0px'  />";
                actions +="</span>";
            return actions;
            }
            },
            {"sTitle":"Starting Bid Price", "sWidth": '10%'},
            {"sTitle":"Current Bid Price", "sWidth": '10%'},
            {
                "sTitle":"Bid",
                "sWidth": '17%',
                "mData": null,
                "bSearchable": false,                               
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (oObj){
                    var actions = "";
                    actions += "<span class='data_actions iconsweet'>\n\
                               <a title='Buy' href='/buyproduct/index/bid/id/" + oObj.aData[0] + "'><img src='/images/buy.png' alt='Buy'  title='Buy' /></a>";
                    actions +="</span>";
                    return actions;
                 }
            }
            <?php if(Qsm_User::isAdmin()){ ?>
            ,{
                "sTitle":"Transaction",
                "sWidth": '22%',
                "mData": null,
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (oObj){
                    var actions1 = "";
                    actions1 += "<span class='data_actions iconsweet'>\n\
                                <a title='Transaction' href='/buyproduct/index/transaction/id/" + oObj.aData[0] + "'><img src='/images/icons/edit3.png' alt='Edit' title='Transaction' /></a>";

                    actions1 +="</span>";
                    return actions1;
                }
            }
            <?php } ?>
        ]
    });     

});
```

Please anybody help me to handle this json formating error

Answer (score 0):

your action will return empty string on no row condition which is invalid json data, Check the value returned from

```
$this->_helper->DataTables($oSelect, array('product_id','e.ename as employee_name','name','brand','conditions','about','image_path','reserved_price','Max(b.bid_amount) as amount'))
```

if null/or no rows echo something like this or empty row data

```
{
   "msg": "no-data"
}
```

Update:

```
public function getProductsAction(){

 $oProductModel = new Application_Model_Db_Table_Products();
 $oSelect = $oProductModel->fetchAllProductItems();
 if($oSelect){
    echo Zend_Json::encode($this->_helper->DataTables($oSelect, array('product_id','e.ename as employee_name','name','brand','conditions','about','image_path','reserved_price','Max(b.bid_amount) as amount')));
 }else{
    echo '{"msg": "no-data"}';  //or edit with empty data matching required by your view
 }
}
```

Comment: how to use this in my code, can you please explain where should i use this

Comment: for no row condition only am getting this error, when there is no data in table. So how to handle this json format error.

Comment: not sure of the data format returned by your helper class, if $oSelect is null on empty row condition use the above code in update:, you can also handle the empty row condition in your helper->DataTables

Comment: without checking whether the table is empty or not how we use if else condition?

Comment: is $oSelect is rowset or query?, could you share some code of $oProductModel->fetchAllProductItems(); and $this->_helper->DataTables  to know how the data is featched